# Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $x^7+5x^2-3=0$. Prove that $x$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I've been working on this past exam and haven't made any progress. I'm trying proof by contradiction be supp. that $x \in \mathbb{Q}, x = \frac{p}{q}$ where $q \neq 0$. Then I get $ \frac{p^7}{q^7} + 5 \frac{p^2}{p^2} = 3 $ but playing around further does not seem to get anywhere.

I also tried Setting $f(x) = x^7+5x^2-3$. Then $f'(x) = x(7x^5+10)$ which gives me two critical points and hence max 3 solutions for $f(x)=0$. I'm also not sure where to go on from here.

**edit** So I did $ \frac{p^7}{q^7} + 5 \frac{p^2}{p^2} = 3 \to p^7+5p^2q^5=3q^7 \to q(3q^6-5p^2q^5) = p^7$ Because $3q^6-5p^2q^5$ is an integer then that implies $q | p^7$ which is a contradiction because $\gcd(p,q)=1$

**edit2** I'm tagging this as proof verification since I came up with a solution in my first edit.

**edit3** While it's quite interesting, our class isn't using the Rational Root Theorem. Instead, were convert the equation in question to the form $p^2(p^5+5q^5)=3q^7$ and showing by cases that for each possibly parities of p, q we either have $\gcd(p,q) \neq 1$ or $p^2(p^5+5q^5) \neq 3q^7$. Also, my first edit is indeed incorrect.

Comment: Lookup the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem#Proofs) and its proofs.

Comment: the $p,q$ approach is right. multiply by $q^7$ and then notice all numbers are integers..

Comment: `that implies q|p^7 which is a contradiction because gcd(p,q)=1` That's not a contradiction, it just implies that $q=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write  $x=\dfrac pq$ in lowest terms, which means $p,q$ are coprime. The equation can be rewritten as
$$p^7+5p^2q^5=p^2(p^5+5q^5)=3q^7$$
So $p$ divides $3q^7$. As it is coprime with $q^7$, *Gauß' lemma* asserts it divides $3$, whence $p=\pm 1$ or $\pm3$.

Also, $q$ divides $p^2(p^5+5q^5)$. So it divides $p^2$ or $p^5+5q^5$. The latter case implies it divides $p^5$. In both cases, as $p$ and $q$ are coprime, it is possible only if $q=\pm1$.

*Conclusion*: if the equation has a rational root, it is necessarily one of $\,\{1,-1,3,-3\}$. Now, it is easy to check that none of them is a root.

*Note:*
In the same way , one proves  the *Rational root theorem*:

> If a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients has a rational root, written in lowest terms as $x=\dfrac pq$, then $p$ divides the constant term of $f$ and $q$ divides its leading coefficient.